# What makes vi chord tonic or subdominant?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, analysis

vi chord has both tonic and subdominant functionalities, and iii chord has both tonic and dominant functionalities.

What decides vi(or iii) chord tonic or subdominant(or dominant)?

For example, in the picture below, vi chord is present in measure 1 and 4.
In measure 1, it is placed after I chord and before IV chord, so I assume it functions as subdominant.
In measure 4, it is placed after V chord, so I assume it functions as dominant.

Likewise, iii chord in measure 4 is placed after tonic chord and at rest, so I assume it functions as tonic chord,
and iii chord in measure 6 is placed between dominant chords so I assume it works as tonic chord.

[image]

Are these assumptions Ok?
Or if not, are there any books or resources on the internet that clarifies such ambiguities?

Comment: This excerpt looks like it came from a popular song, and modern popular music does not adhere strongly to functional harmonic rules. This example is not a good one for study. Instead, use classical music from between 1700 and 1900, which is what functional harmony is built to describe.

Comment: Some comments regarding functional interpretation of the III and VI chords within various theoretical branches can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submediant

Answer (score 1):

My analysis is a bit different. I see the first Em as just a "color" chord; it does not act as a functional chord. It does make for smooth voice-leading in a pattern that's part of the Ice-Cream-Cone-Progression: I-vi-IV-V (or I-vi-ii-V, etc.) Sometimes the chord symbols tend to "absorb" a moving bass line (or internal voice). (In a now-defunct musical website, someone analyzed a C-Major chord over a C-B-A-G descending bass as a progression of C-B-A-G chords with some additions and omissions.)

In measure 4, the Em is part of a deceptive cadence so as not to sound too final.

The B-minor chord looks like a substitute for a D7 chord or a D chord with a non-chord tone added.

Lead sheets are often inaccurate as the chord symbols get bass lines and melodies absorbed into the symbol. Roman Numerals can have the same problem. Even Thorough Bass treated in this manner looks like a succession of telephone numbers. I write my lead sheets with simple chord symbols, a few sevenths and ninths (I use slashes for the chords, not to spell out the bass line). The players can walk their bass lines and add more thirds on top depending on style and day-of-the-week.

Comment: Just interested - where did the 'Ice-Cream-Cone-Progression get its name? Only ever known it as 1-6-4-5.

Comment: I read that somewhere in a book on popular music progressions. It's also in Mozart and Vivaldi (and probably somewhere in Gregorian Chant.)

Comment: Didn't realise monks ate ice cream in cones!

Answer (score -1):

You're correct about the `vi` chords, but both apparent `iii` chords are acting relative to the following `IV` chords. In that sense, they're serving a dominant-like function relative to `IV` — i.e., `vii/IV`. Even that isn't wholly correct, since a true `vii/IV` in this case would have an F natural rather than F#.